# Object to array in JavaScript (Lodash, Azure Function, Azure Logic App)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, azure-functions, lodash

The goal is to, on a timer, extract JSON from a proprietary content management system, transform it into a CSV, and deposit that CSV in an Office 365 shared drive.

The combination of an Azure Function and Azure Logic App make this possible. In its current state the Node/JavaScript Azure Function (code below) (1) successfully retrieves the JSON object and (2) successfully sends an object to the Azure Logic App, which successfully receives it.

After that, the Logic App has a built-in JSON-to-CSV "action". The input must be in an array.

From [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#create-csv-table-action):

[image]

However, despite much struggle I am unsuccessful turning the object into an array.

Because I am familiar with the basics of the jq JSON manipulation language, I spent much time with the [node-jq](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-jq) npm package. I was unsuccessful. So I turned to [Lodash](https://lodash.com). Following the JSON and code below are a sliver of my failed attempts.

### Original JSON:

```
[
    {
        "Challenge": {
            "Group": {
                "Name": "Challenge group name"
            }
        },
        "Name": "Name",
        "Description": "Description",
        "CreatedDate": "2020-10-01",
        "Url": "https://url",
        "Category": {
            "Name": "Category name"
        },
        "TotalVotes": 1,
        "YesVotes": 2,
        "NoVotes": 3,
        "CurrentStatus": {
            "Status": {
                "Name": "Current status status name"
            },
            "Author": {
                "DisplayName": "Current status author display name"
            },
            "CreatedDate": "2020-10-01"
        }
    },
<99 more>
]
```

### Desired result:

Some array keys are changed from JSON source keys.

```
[
    {
        "Group": "Challenge group name" (which is Challenge.Group.Name),
        "Title": "Name" (which is Name),
        "User": "Current status author display name" (which is CurrentStatus.Author.DisplayName),
        "Category": "Category name" (which is Category.Name),
        "Status": "Current status status name" (which is CurrentStatus.Status.Name),
        "CreatedDate": "2020-10-01" (which is CreatedDate),
        "TotalVotes": 1 (which is TotalVotes),
        "YesVotes": 2 (which is YesVotes),
        "NoVotes": 3 (which is NoVotes),
        "URL": "https://url" (which is Url)
    },
<99 more>
]
```

### Azure Function code

The purpose of printing a "test" object with `fs` is simply to show me the output in a way that is more convenient given that the console log returns 100 objects, which are much longer than the simplified example provided above. The `fs` code will not be included in the final.

```
module.exports = function (context, myTimer) {
    var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();
  
    var request = require("request");
    var fetch = require("node-fetch");
    const _ = require("lodash");
    var jsonPath = "file.json";
    var fs = require("fs");
    var options = {
      url:
        "<content management system endpoint>",
      headers: {
        "Rest-User-Token": "<token>",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };
  
    function callback(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var info = JSON.parse(body);
        var result = info.Ideas;
  

        <Unsuccessful object-to-array coding attempts - see a sliver of examples below>


        fs.writeFile(jsonPath, JSON.stringify(result), function (err) {
          if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
          }
        });
  
        function send() {
          const azureLogicAppUrl =
            "<Azure logic app endpoint>";
          fetch(azureLogicAppUrl, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(info),
          })
            //Sends JSON to Azure Logic App
            .then((response) => response.text()) // or .json(), not sure
            .then((json) => context.log(json));
        }
        send();
      }
    }
    request(options, callback);
  };
```

### Failed attempts (a small number)

#### Attempt

```
var flat = _.flatMap(result, 'Name');
```

#### Result

```
["123","456","789","012","345",<etc>]
```

#### Attempt

```
const arr = (result, keyAs) => _.values(_.mapValues(result, (value, key) => { value[keyAs] = key; return value; }));
```

#### Result

```
undefined
```

#### Attempt

```
result.blocks = _(result.blocks)
.map('Name')
.value();
```

#### Result

```
result is not defined
```

#### Attempt

```
_.map(info, (obj, key) => {
obj.symbol = key
return obj
 })
```

#### Result

Seems to do nothing

I am not a professional coder, please forgive my lack of knowledge and thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, Azure context aside, you want to convert your original JSON into desired (flat) format.

Here's a basic version for which you don't need any external dependencies:

convert-to-flat-array.js

```js
const sourceArray = [
    {
        "Challenge": {
            "Group": {
                "Name": "Challenge group name"
            }
        },
        "Name": "Name",
        "Description": "Description",
        "CreatedDate": "2020-10-01",
        "Url": "https://url",
        "Category": {
            "Name": "Category name"
        },
        "TotalVotes": 1,
        "YesVotes": 2,
        "NoVotes": 3,
        "CurrentStatus": {
            "Status": {
                "Name": "Current status status name"
            },
            "Author": {
                "DisplayName": "Current status author display name"
            },
            "CreatedDate": "2020-10-01"
        }
    },
]

const flatArray = sourceArray.map((item) => ({
    Group: item.Challenge.Group.Name,
    Title: item.Name,
    User: item.CurrentStatus.Author.DisplayName,
    Category: item.Category.Name,
    Status: item.CurrentStatus.Status.Name,
    CreatedDate: item.CreatedDate,
    TotalVotes: item.TotalVotes,
    YesVotes: item.YesVotes,
    NoVotes: item.NoVotes,
    URL: item.Url,
}))

console.log(flatArray)
```

which results in

```sh
 ~ $ node convert-to-flat-array.js 
[
  {
    Group: 'Challenge group name',
    Title: 'Name',
    User: 'Current status author display name',
    Category: 'Category name',
    Status: 'Current status status name',
    CreatedDate: '2020-10-01',
    TotalVotes: 1,
    YesVotes: 2,
    NoVotes: 3,
    URL: 'https://url'
  }
]
```

Comment: This worked - thank you. My only question is that the punctuation is turned into HTML: `&quot;administering department&quot;`, `Partner&#39;s`. I know CSV tables can be messy here, and there may not be a way around it, but thought I would ask anyway.

Comment: Can you confirm whether raw output from Azure has the HTML entities or if it's the viewing application that converts quotes?

Comment: Now that I have checked, it is being delivered with HTML from the content management system at the very beginning of the process. The JavaScript you provided had nothing to do with it. Sorry about that.